# GDAL reclassify and polygonize Esri ASCII grid files

Tags: gdal, reclassify, polygonize, esri-ascii-raster

I realized that reclassification is the tool to go to reduce the polygon count [Creating simplified (binned) polygons from raster file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242558/creating-simplified-binned-polygons-from-raster-file) and implemented it in Java using geotools. Unfortunately this is really frustrating due to JAI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341018/jai-cant-execute-in-native-spark-only-in-sbt-and-as-a-separate-scala-function

So I want to try it instead using GDAL. Here is a dummy file. How can I interlink gdal_polygonize.py and http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc steps is it required to write output to file?

```
ncols 4
nrows 3
xllcorner 0
yllcorner 0
cellsize 1
nodata_value -999
-1 -2 -3 -4
-4 -21 -3 -3
-3 -2 -31 -1
```

There should be 2 classes `[-50 -10[, [-10 0[`